# when the new element is created by Javascript, the tag wont work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

For rough example, I have a table

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>wangel</td>
    <td>tamang</td>
    <td><a class="edit">edit</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

when i click edit, i use a function using j query, use Ajax and then call the function, do edit query with PHP and then i return new row which has now been edited

```
<tr>
   < td >wangelpakhrin    </ td>
   <td>tamang</td>
   <td><a class="edit">edit</td>
</tr>
```

then, replace with the older one using replace With() .
now, the problem is that the new edit wont trigger the function i created earlier in script , else it refreshes the page.
i did using live() or on() but still it refreshes the page. 
what can be the solution towards it? it would be very helpful thanks.

the script code

```
$("a.edit").on("click",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr("value");
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        $.post("../lib/ajax/edit-user.php",{id:id},function(data){

            parent.parent().replaceWith(data);


            });


});
```

Comment: It is hard to help without your jquery code

Comment: you need to share how the edit handler is written but the problem is not using event delegation

Comment: Have u tried adding `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: yes i did it, i forgot to put it there XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that your table is fixed and you add a tr inside the table.Then make a class for your table tag like

```
<table class="my_table">
<tr>
    <td>wangel</td>
    <td>tamang</td>
    <td><a class="edit">edit</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

now your .on function like

```
$(".my_table").on('click',".edit",function(){

    //your work
});
```

please let me know the status.

Comment: thank you so much aritra chakarborty, now the on() works fine. i added the table class name and the edit works fine ... u saved my time..

Answer (score 0):

you can update only content of your  instead of replacing like this:

```
$("a.edit").on("click",function(e) {

var id = $(this).attr("value");
var parent = $(this).parent();
$.post("../lib/ajax/edit-user.php",{id:id},function(data){

    parent.parent().empty().html(data);


    });
 });
```

Your data must be returned in form of s.

```
data=" <td>wangel New</td><td>tamang new</td><td><a class="edit">edit</a></td>"
```

Comment: empty or replace works fine. now when i click a tag of the new row, it wont trigger the a.edit function